# Pass value in LINQ to Call method

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method in my code. I want to call this method from LINQ. How can I do this ? I want to pass different time like Annual, Monthly, weekly, and daily

```
private Time DecideMinTime(IEnumerable<Time> g) {  }
```

Here is the LINQ from which I am trying to call this method

```
 var exportRuns =
            this.exportInformationRepository.GetAll()
                .GroupBy(ei => new { ei.StartDate, ei.StudyIdentifier })
                .Select(
                    g =>
                    new ExportRun()
                        {
                            ExportInformations = g,     
                            MinimumTimeGranularity = DecideMinTime(), //Call the method
                            StartDate = g.Key.StartDate,
                            StudyIdentifier = g.Key.StudyIdentifier
                        });

        return exportRuns;
```

What to pass in that method to IEnumerable g

Comment: This depends on the type of objects you are querying here.

Comment: How would *we* know what *you* want to pass to your method?

Comment: looks like you don't want to pass in an `IEnumerable`  since you're already iterating over it? It's hard to tell without the implementation of `DecideMinTime`...edit: understand `IEnumerable` now.. thanks @cdhowie

Comment: @mckeejm There is a group going on here, so `g` is an enumerable of some type that probably has the property in question.

Comment: Please be more clear about what you're trying to achieve. Also, show us what type of object `this.exportInformationRepository.GetAll()` is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that the objects you are grouping have some property of type `Time`.  If we assume that it's called `Foo` then you would do something like:

```
MinimumTimeGranularity = DecideMinTime(g.Select(i => i.Foo)),
```

Comment: It wouldn't be `g`, though; I think that's his group object.

Comment: @JustinMorgan `DecideMinTime()` aggregates a `Time` object by selecting the smallest one (it's another SO question he asked), so he needs some sequence of `Time` objects -- presumably this comes from the particular group.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. It's hard to tell exactly what he's trying to do, and he's also used `g` as an identifier in two different places. I withdraw my comment.

Comment: In fact, I see from his other question that his `Time` type isn't a time at all, but an enum he created. Wow.